# A turing machine which computes the same language as a "stay put" turing machine

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Im not sure I really understand how stay put machines work. I know they are just like turing machines but with states. So they can "stay put". But what confuses me is when you define a FSA for a turing machine it has a state. Doesn't it stay put with this state? Could someone show me an example of a language using an FSA which is accepted on a stay put machine and a turing machine.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your definition, a stay-put machine is a Turing machine whose head can only move right or stay on the current tape cell ("stay put"); it can't move left.

A stay put machine is significantly less powerful than an ordinary Turing machine. A stay put machine can only recognize regular languages.